# How to allow multiple images being upload at once in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I have a form that allow multiple images being upload. But when check at the console. only first image is being shown in console.

[image]

console.log `C:\fakepath\avatar.jpg`

HTML

```
<form name="addListingForm" id="addListingForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadImage" id="uploadImage" accept="image/*" multiple="" onChange="makeFileList();">
    <div id="fileList">No Image Selected</div>
</form>
<button type="button" id="btnUpload" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
```

JS

```
$("#btnUpload").on("click",function(){
    var uploadImage = $("#uploadImage").val();
    var fd = new FormData();
    var files = $('#uploadImage')[0].files[0];
    fd.append('file',files);
    console.log(files)
    var params = JSON.stringify(files);
    $.ajax({
        // The Image will be upload using ajax tp DB
    });
});

function makeFileList() {
    var input = document.getElementById("uploadImage");
    var ul = document.getElementById("fileList");
    while (ul.hasChildNodes()) {
        ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = input.files[i].name;
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    if (!ul.hasChildNodes()) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = 'No Image Selected';
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have access to both files in the for loop iteration then you can start your upload function there.

Comment: got example to show?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#btnUpload").on("click", function() {
  var uploadImage = $("#uploadImage").val();
  var files = $('#uploadImage')[0].files;

  var promises = uploadImages(files);
  $.when(...promises).done(function(...args) {
    //handle the resulting data here which is an array containing the data
    console.log(args)
  })
});

function uploadImages(files) {
  return $.map(files, function(file) {
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("image", file, file.name);

    var settings = {
      "url": "https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=516c7e69e9c260a2a00eacceafdb1d62",
      "method": "POST",
      "timeout": 0,
      "processData": false,
      "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
      "contentType": false,
      "data": formdata
    };

    return $.ajax(settings).then(function(res) {
      var result = JSON.parse(res)

      return result.data.url
    })
  })
}

function makeFileList() {
  var input = document.getElementById("uploadImage");
  var ul = document.getElementById("fileList");
  while (ul.hasChildNodes()) {
    ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = input.files[i].name;
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  if (!ul.hasChildNodes()) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = 'No Image Selected';
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="addListingForm" id="addListingForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadImage" id="uploadImage" accept="image/*" multiple="" onChange="makeFileList();">
    <div id="fileList">No Image Selected</div>
</form>
<button type="button" id="btnUpload" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
```

Comment: Hi, i am trying to use your solution, I try upload 2 images and it will upload to other server using API, maybe you want to replicate to real situation, it is successful upload both images, but why at the console still only 1 image is appear? another 1 is not appearing. I have update my code above at original posting.

Comment: I have modified the answer.